# What's the meaning of '[m' and how to get rid of it in this expression?

Tags: bash, shell, special-characters

First of all, a little description of the environment:

- Bash 5
- Default MacOS Terminal

In my `bash_profile` I have declared the following function to quickly see all the IPv4 that my computer has:

```sh
YB=$(tput setaf 11)
WB=$(tput setaf 15)
RESET=$(tput sgr0)

lanconfig() {
  for ip in $(ifconfig | grep inet\ | cut -f 2 -d \ ); do
    echo -e "$WB LAN IP:$YB ${ip:3} $RESET"
  done
}
```

With that function all works perfect and I get the following output:

```
 LAN IP: 127.0.0.1 
 LAN IP: 192.168.1.100
```

Where `LAN IP:` get white color and the actual IP address get yellow.

Now you know the background, let's suppose for one minute that the `echo` inside the function instead perform a parameter expansion over `$ip`, it just prints the var. Something like:

```sh
echo -e "$WB LAN IP:$YB $ip $RESET"
```

With that `echo`, the yellow color doesn't apply to the IP. I was in shock, I don't understand. Doing some test with parameter expansion, I was being able to find that the expansion `${ip:1}` prints `[m127.0.0.1`

The questions are:

1. What does `[m` means?
2. Why `[m` is in the var?
3. Is it worth it to get rid of that character? How?

Comment: Pretty sure that's an ANSI color code. If that was correct you can get rid of it.

Comment: @raaowx : Looks like you were catching color escape codes when setting `ip`. There should also be an _escape_ character in it (check this with `xxd <<<"$ip"`). `cut` doesn't produce them, so it is either `ifconfig` (test it with `ifconfig|xxd`)  or `grep`. In the latter case, I would conclude that you have set the environment variable `GREP_OPTIONS` to something causing colouring.

Comment: @user1934428 maybe my alias grep=‘grep —color=always’ is interfering?

Comment: @user1934428 I can confirm now that the alias `grep='grep --color=always'` was the problem.

Comment: **Never** ever use the same name for an alias as for the command you are aliasing to. You could do a `alias g='grep --color=always'`. Usually, we use aliases for things done on the command line only, not in the body of a function or script, and calling it `g` is easier to type too.

Comment: @user1934428 yeah! in the past I thought it was a good option. Now I clearly see that I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to get rid of that `[m` characters. Answering my own questions:

1. What does `[m` means?

Well, it is part of an ANSI color codes used in terminals for cosmetic or readability purposes. You can find more info in @neon answer.

2. Why `[m` is in the var?

It was a little bit tricky to find out but the ANSI color code was entering as part of the var because of the loop expresion `$(ifconfig | grep inet\ | cut -f 2 -d \ )`. I have an alias for `grep` that do `grep --color=always`. Because of this alias, `grep` always include the ANSI color code surrounding the matched text, so `$ip` contains the actual IP address and the ANSI color code.

3. Is it worth it to get rid of that character? How?

Yeah, it is totally worth. In fact, I've learned something new. The alias `grep=grep --color=always` is not worth because could cause this kind of troubles. Now, I think is better to use `grep --color=auto` so `grep` only apply color when the output is going to the terminal `stdout`. You can find more info in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236960/what-does-the-color-auto-option-for-gnu-grep-mean).

About "How?", I think my last paragraph explains that but the solution was:

Change alias `grep='grep --color=always'` with `grep='grep --color=auto'` and remove the parameter expansion in the `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

These are ANSI color codes. They are responsible for the colors and some other formatting. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Prakasaka/219fe5695beeb4d6311583e79933a009) you have a short overview of what is available. Basically you can remove such sequences, they are purely cosmetic - of course only if you are not interested in the colors or, for example, bold font. Many people (myself included) like to build such things into scripts and the like to improve the readability.

For more information see [the article in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization). It is a good starting point if you are interested.

Comment: Yeah, you were totally right. There was an ANSI color that comes from my `grep` alias. I have `grep` as an alias of `grep --color=always`. Because of that alias, `$ip` in the `for` retrieves the IP and the ANSI color.